# Closed Sub-Neighborhoods of 0 in Topological Vector Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I've been studying Conway's functional analysis and the following questions occurred to me: Let $X$ be a topological vector space. It is known that any neighborhood of the origin contains a balanced sub-neighborhood (follows reasonably straightforwardly from multiplication being continuous). But what about the following:

1. If $U$ is open and $0 \in U$, does there exist a closed set $F \subset U$ with $0\in int(F)$ ($int(F)$ is the interior of $F$)?
2. It seems that a balanced sub-neighborhood of the origin is sort of meant to take the place of a "ball" in a metric space. Clearly any open set $U$ in a metric space satisfies that for all $x\in U$, there exist closed $F$ and open $U_0$ so that $x\in U_0 \subset F \subset  U$. Is there a name for this property? Does this property hold in all topological vector spaces?

Comment: As $\emptyset$ is both open and closed, every set in any topological space has an open set $U_0 = \emptyset$ and closed set $F = \emptyset$ with $U_0 \subset F \subset U$. I suggest you consider something a little harder, like "for each $x \in U$, there is an open set $U_0$ with $x \in U_0 \subset \overline {U_0} \subset U$", or more compactly: "Every neighborhood of a point $x$ has a closed subneighborhood." One could call it "Locally closed", but that term already has a different meaning.

Comment: Thanks @PaulSinclair! I neglected that very important condition that these should be neighborhoods of points in $U$. I've corrected this now, and clearly this condition is satisfied for TVS's. I wonder if this condition has a name though in topology?

Comment: After parsing it out, this is just "regular". For any point $x$ and closed set $C$ with $x \notin C$, there exist disjoint neighborhoods of both. $U$ is the complement of $C$, $U_0$ is the neighborhood of $x$, and the complement of $\overline U_0$ is the neighborhood of $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a $0$-neighbourhood $U$ in a topological vector space, the continuity of the sum at $(0,0)$ yields an open $0$-neighbourhood $V$ with $V+V\subseteq U$ and then $V\subseteq \overline V \subseteq U$. The first inclusion is clear and to show the second, for every $x\in \overline V$, there is $y\in \overline V$ with $x-y\in V$ so that $x=(x-y)+y\in V+V\subseteq U$.

Comment: Amazing thanks! Do you know if the property in 2 has a name?